# JQuery autocomplete does not always fire

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, intermittent

Can anyone think of any reasons as to why my JQuery autocomplete does not always show its suggestion menu? I always type the same valid keywords but the results do not always show up.

This is the JS I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#q").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        delay: 350,
        source: "ac.php"
    });
});
```

When I check Firefox's web console it shows that it's loaded ac.php with the OK status code. I try different keywords and none of them show up. This is all intermittent though as if I reload the page a few times or close the browser, it sometimes works again.

When I manually go to ac.php?term=whatever, it ALWAYS shows results for valid keywords.

However, when I set source to ["Hi", "there"], it works correctly.

I'm loading these in the head tag of the document:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

edit: The function that returns data to ac.php

```
    private function to_json($results)
    {
        $output = array();

        foreach($results as $result)
        {
            $output[] = $result->name; // nothing is escaped here
        }

        if(sizeof($output) > 1)
        {
            $uniques = array_unique($output);

            $buffer = array();

            foreach($uniques as $unique)
            {
                $buffer[] = $unique;
            }

            $output = $buffer;
        }

        return json_encode($output);
    }
```

Sample output:

```
["Sennheiser MM-100 Stereo Bluetooth 2.0 Headset Invisible Mic USB","Polycom VSX7000E W\/POWERCAM CAMERA\/ Soundstation VTX1000\/MIC\/CODE54 (Maintenance Contract Required)","Polycom HDX 7000-720 Kit W\/ Eagle Eye HD Camera HDX Mic","Polycom HDX 6000-720V Kit W\/ Eagle Eye HD Camera Mic Remote"]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is ac.php like? It may be an issue there?

Comment: If you posted a fiddle we could see what's going on rather than guessing from the limited information... See http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKSxv/) you asked for. Sorry, not too sure how to use that site.

Comment: How about ac.php? What does it look like?

Comment: ac.php just calls the to_json() file up above. I'll edit an output from it above.

Comment: I just looked it over and it seems that it might be that particular page that doesn't work. If you edit the dom and add more divs/remove divs, is dom ready still functional?

Comment: What is going on in that `document.ready`? Looks like you're recreating the form and rebinding the events on user input, why? Maybe there's some sort of conflict in that `keyup` code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try in this way. Mine is working in this way :-

$(".autocomplete_text").autocomplete("ac.php", {
        multiple: true,
        mustMatch: false,
        autoFill: false
});